# Sql get minimum value from multiple tables based on date

Tags: sql, sql-server

example :

```
    Table B                        Table A
ID Item   Record                  ID  Date
1   pen    10                     1   1/1/2015
1   CD     40                     2   7/3/2015
2   pen    20                     3   5/8/2016
2   CD     50                     4   10/12/2016 
3   pen    8
3   CD     30
3   pen    5
4   pen    10
4   CD     35
```

result into this:

```
ID  Item  Record  LowestRecord Date
1   pen     10        10       1/1/2015
1   CD      40        40       1/1/2015
2   pen     20        10       7/3/2015
2   CD      50        40       7/3/2015
3   pen     8         5        5/8/2016
3   CD      30        30       5/8/2016
3   pen     5         5        5/8/2016
4   pen     10        5        10/12/2016
4   CD      35        30       10/12/2016
```

so it select minimum value until the current date record.
thanks in advance.

Comment: it's select based on date in the header table where Date <= current record date

Comment: Why isn't this just a join between the tables on `id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions, where you group the records by item, and limit the frame only be for records with date less than equal the date of the current record, then take the min.

```
SELECT a.*
    , min(a.record) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY b.[Date] DESC 
          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS LowestRecord
    , b.[DATE]
FROM
    a JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: @RBT explanation added.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming date column is of date type, you can join the row tables like this:

```
select
    a.*,
    min(a.record) over (partition by item order by b.date, b.id) minrecord,
    b.date
from tableA a
inner join tableB b
on a.id = b.id;
```